# query to select all tables from database but not materialized views

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am selecting all tables from database by using query

```
select table_name from all_tables where owner='XYZ' order by table_name
```

But above query is also returning materialized view. How can I get only tables and not materialized view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can ignore the materialized views and their log tables (if they exist) with

```
select *
  from all_tables t
 where owner = user
   and (owner, table_name) not in (select owner, mview_name
                                     from all_mviews l
                                   union all
                                   select log_owner, log_table
                                     from all_mview_logs)
```

Comment: I would like to know what is use of "l" in line "from all_mviews l"

Comment: @ShivamTiwari not needed, you can remove it if you want